# Should you replace your refresh token after getting a new one for Microsoft Grpah API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token, refresh-token

Since the access token is short lived, I used the refresh token to get a new access token. A successful token response will include the following (example from [microsoft api doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)):

`{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...",
"token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "user.read%20mail.read",
    "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4...",
}`

I have read the life time of refresh_token is valid until revoked or 90 days of inactivity. Since I'm getting a new refresh token, do I need to replace the old refresh token with this new one? if I do, how to delete the old refresh token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like access token  Refresh tokens will also expire but are rather long-lived i.e., 90 days maximum time. Once Refresh token expires you need to authenticate to  the application again to get a new access token and refresh token.

Also please refer [MS Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

Comment: thanks! but I thought the maximum inactive time for refresh token is 90 days? which means if I keep using it every day, the refresh token won't be expired?

Comment: Hi @Angie, No It is not  inactive time. It is the maximum time we can use the refresh token.After 90 days we need to authenticate to get new refresh token.